# No guarda el id (autoincremental) de mi tabla en MySQL Workbench 8.0 y Xammp V3.2.2

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, xampp

Espero y me puedan echar un cable; Tengo la siguiente tabla [image: select, tabla y errores]

Ejecuto el select `select * from tipoempleado where nombre="CONFIANZA";` y me aparece el error en la fila 17 (el 1054.....columna nombre desconocida). No sé a qué se deba ni como solucionar ese error.

En la tabla agregué una fila (la primera con nombre 'lkm') y se me guardó como se muestra (sin el valor autoincremental, lo cual es raro porque ese campo se debería agregar de forma automática y al crear dicha tabla ese campo lo puse como PRIMARY KEY y NOT NULL porque es la llave primaria).

Luego metí otra fila (tipoempleado '3' y nombre 'lkml') y también se guardó correctamente, no sé qué ocurre.

En la información de la tabla, el valor del autoincrement no aparece :o (a pesar de que se quedó en valor 3, que yo se agregué manualmente): [image: Autoincrement (vacío)].

Nota: también probé con Xampp v3.2.4 y sigue el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Debes setear el AUTOINCREMENT cuando creas la base de datos chequeando la opción AI, no se establece de manera automática dicho seteo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema parecía venir porque creé las tablas a través de un modelo ER usando el asistente de modelos ER de Workbench (todo gráfico). Tuve que rehacer mi base de datos pero esta vez con puro código de forma manual. El problemas desapareció una vez que ejecuté el script que creé manualmente. Espero y a alguien le sirva este dato y haga desde un principio su base de datos de forma manual.